# MySQL: Troubleshoot Sub Select in Left Join

Tags: mysql, subquery, left-join

This is probably very basic, but I'm not experienced at all with sub selects.

I have two tables: `prm_album` and `gallery_meta`. `prm_album` stores name and id for each album, `gallery_meta` stores image details for every image of every album. The involved columns are thus:

```
prm_album:        ID, Name
gallery_meta:     FileName, AlbumID, FileExt, IsDefault, Created
```

I'm trying to combine two queries - one gave me a list of albums, another gave me thumbnail info for each of those albums. I want to end up with a single array this time where I can get each album's name, id, and it's default (or first) image's info.

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Abbr, a.Name, p.FileName, p.FileExt 
FROM prm_album a
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT FileName, FileExt
    FROM gallery_meta 
    ORDER BY (IsDefault = 1) DESC, Created ASC
    LIMIT 0,1 ) AS p
ON (a.ID = p.AlbumID)
WHERE 1
```

When put through the console, this throws the error `Unknown column 'p.AlbumID' in 'on clause'`. All advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Abbr, a.Name, p.FileName, p.FileExt 
FROM prm_album a
LEFT JOIN gallery_meta p
  ON p.AlbumID=a.ID
GROUP BY a.ID
ORDER BY p.IsDefault DESC, p.Created ASC
```

Comment: Didnt think at all of GROUP - and this also allows for no Default to be specified. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your query, it can't find p.AlbumID because you didn't select it in your subquery.  However, if there's only one `IsDefault` for every album:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Abbr, a.Name, p.FileName, p.FileExt 
FROM prm_album a
LEFT JOIN
gallery_meta p ON (a.ID = p.AlbumID AND p.IsDefault = 1)
```